# Fetch data from one database to another database on another server mysql using web sockets

Tags: php, mysql, websocket, phpwebsocket

I want to copy data from one database to another database on another server in realtime. I have some limitations though.

1. I can't use triggers with federated engines.
2. I can't use database replications.

My solution: I created an API on server A to push the data, I wrote some code on server B that gets the data and pushes it to the database on server B, with the help of a cron job, I am able to make this almost realtime. Unfortunately, the client is not satisfied with this approach, so I want to use websockets. I am not too sure about how to go about it, all the tutorials I came across are using websockets are to create chat applications. Does anyone have any experience doing this kind of thing or can someone point me in a direction or a resource? My application must be in PHP.

On server A, I can only use PHP, I can't install any frameworks or install dependencies or have access to any dependency managers.

On server B, I have access to create PHP applications and do anything PHP, including using Laravel or any other kind of frameworks.

Comment: Well, if you want to use websockets, then you should not want to use mysql directly as mysql does not provide any notification feature. You need a message queue or some in-memory database / cache with notification features, otherwise you need to go batck to the good old polling method with mysql, which is not going to be realtime.

Comment: Is this an intranet solution or does it require to go out on the internet ?